# The DFS browser cannot browse anything else but a distributed file system

Tags: eclipse, hadoop

I have installed hadoop 1.2.1  (all on single machine). I am getting an error in eclipse that
'The DFS browser cannot browse anything else but a distributed file system'.
Also tried with changing core-site.xml value

```
<value>hdfs://localhost:50040</value>
to
<value>hdfs://[your IP]:50040</value>
```

[image: eclipse snap]

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure your NameNode is running at port 50040. If you have not changed it then it would be running on port 9000. Also, make sure that your Hadoop plugin contains all the required jars in it.